# How do you get all info from GeoJSON layer in Openlayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, geojson

In OpenLayers I have added a GeoJSON layer (of the world) and created a simple infotool.
The GeoJSON layer contains multiple features for some countries.

If I click on a country I only get one result, but I would like to see all the results in the infobox.

The infobox I have created like this:

```
            landgrab.events.on({
            featureselected: function(event) {
                var feature = event.feature;
                var country = feature.attributes.landgrabbed;
                var landgrabber = feature.attributes.landgrabber;
                var landgrabber_country = feature.attributes.base;
                var hectares = feature.attributes.hectares;
                var output = country + "<br/><br/>Land taken by: " + landgrabber + "<br/>From country:  " + landgrabber_country + "<br/>Hectares:  " + hectares;
                document.getElementById("output-id").innerHTML = output;
            }
        });
```

An example of the GeoJSON layer is:

```
{ "type": "Feature", "id": 2, "properties": { "landgrabbed": "Angola", "landgrabber": "CAMC Engineering Co. Ltd", "base": "China", "sector": "Construction", "hectares": 1500.0, "production": "Rice", "projected_investment": "US$77 million", "status_of_deal": "Done ", "isoa3": "AGO" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 16.326528354567046, -5.877470391466218 ], [ 16.573179965896145, -6.622644545115094 ], [ 16.86019087084523, -7.222297865429979 ], [ 17.089995965247169, -7.545688978712477 ], [ 17.472970004962292, -8.068551120641658 ], [ 18.134221632569052, -7.987677504104866 ], [ 18.464175652752687, -7.847014255406478 ], [ 19.016751743249671, -7.98824594486014 ], [ 19.166613396896082, -7.738183688999726 ], [ 19.417502475673217, -7.155428562044278 ], [ 20.037723016040218, -7.11636117923166 ], [ 20.09162153492062, -6.943090101756951 ], [ 20.601822950938327, -6.939317722199689 ], [ 20.51474816252653, -7.299605808138665 ], [ 21.728110792739756, -7.290872491081316 ], [ 21.746455926203367, -7.920084730667114 ], [ 21.94913089365204, -8.305900974158305 ], [ 21.801801385187957, -8.908706556842986 ], [ 21.875181919042404, -9.523707777548566 ], [ 22.208753289486424, -9.89479623783653 ], [ 22.155268182064333, -11.084801120653779 ], [ 22.402798292742432, -10.993075453335692 ], [ 22.837345411884769, -11.017621758674338 ], [ 23.456790805767469, -10.867863457892483 ], [ 23.912215203555746, -10.926826267137542 ], [ 24.017893507592618, -11.237298272347118 ], [ 23.904153680118242, -11.722281589406336 ], [ 24.079905226342902, -12.191296888887308 ], [ 23.930922072045377, -12.565847670138822 ], [ 24.016136508894704, -12.911046237848552 ], [ 21.933886346125945, -12.898437188369357 ], [ 21.887842644953878, -16.080310153876894 ], [ 22.56247846852429, -16.898451429921835 ], [ 23.215048455506093, -17.523116143465955 ], [ 21.377176141045595, -17.93063648851971 ], [ 18.956186964603631, -17.789094740472237 ], [ 18.263309360434221, -17.309950860262006 ], [ 14.209706658595053, -17.353100681225712 ], [ 14.058501417709039, -17.423380629142656 ], [ 13.462362094789967, -16.971211846588744 ], [ 12.814081251688407, -16.941342868724078 ], [ 12.215461460019384, -17.111668389558062 ], [ 11.73419884608515, -17.301889336824502 ], [ 11.640096062881611, -16.673142185129208 ], [ 11.778537224991567, -15.793816013250691 ], [ 12.123580763404448, -14.878316338767931 ], [ 12.175618930722266, -14.449143568583892 ], [ 12.500095249083017, -13.547699883684402 ], [ 12.738478631245442, -13.137905775609937 ], [ 13.312913852601838, -12.483630466362513 ], [ 13.633721144269828, -12.038644707897191 ], [ 13.738727654686926, -11.297863050993143 ], [ 13.686379428775297, -10.731075941615842 ], [ 13.387327915102162, -10.373578383020728 ], [ 13.120987583069876, -9.766897067914115 ], [ 12.875369500386569, -9.166933689005489 ], [ 12.929061313537801, -8.959091078327575 ], [ 13.236432732809874, -8.562629489784342 ], [ 12.933040398824318, -7.596538588087753 ], [ 12.72829837408392, -6.927122084178805 ], [ 12.227347039446443, -6.294447523629373 ], [ 12.322431674863566, -6.100092461779653 ], [ 12.735171339578699, -5.965682061388478 ], [ 13.02486941900699, -5.984388929878108 ], [ 13.375597364971895, -5.864241224799557 ], [ 16.326528354567046, -5.877470391466218 ] ] ], [ [ [ 12.436688266660923, -5.684303887559224 ], [ 12.182336866920281, -5.789930515163803 ], [ 11.914963006242118, -5.037986748884734 ], [ 12.318607618873926, -4.606230157086159 ], [ 12.62075971848455, -4.438023369976122 ], [ 12.995517205465205, -4.781103203961919 ], [ 12.631611769265845, -4.991271254092936 ], [ 12.468004184629763, -5.248361504744992 ], [ 12.436688266660923, -5.684303887559224 ] ] ] ] } }
,
{ "type": "Feature", "id": 3, "properties": { "landgrabbed": "Angola", "landgrabber": "ENI", "base": "Italy", "sector": "Energy", "hectares": 12000.0, "production": "Oil palm", "projected_investment": null, "status_of_deal": "In process", "isoa3": "AGO" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 16.326528354567046, -5.877470391466218 ], [ 16.573179965896145, -6.622644545115094 ], [ 16.86019087084523, -7.222297865429979 ], [ 17.089995965247169, -7.545688978712477 ], [ 17.472970004962292, -8.068551120641658 ], [ 18.134221632569052, -7.987677504104866 ], [ 18.464175652752687, -7.847014255406478 ], [ 19.016751743249671, -7.98824594486014 ], [ 19.166613396896082, -7.738183688999726 ], [ 19.417502475673217, -7.155428562044278 ], [ 20.037723016040218, -7.11636117923166 ], [ 20.09162153492062, -6.943090101756951 ], [ 20.601822950938327, -6.939317722199689 ], [ 20.51474816252653, -7.299605808138665 ], [ 21.728110792739756, -7.290872491081316 ], [ 21.746455926203367, -7.920084730667114 ], [ 21.94913089365204, -8.305900974158305 ], [ 21.801801385187957, -8.908706556842986 ], [ 21.875181919042404, -9.523707777548566 ], [ 22.208753289486424, -9.89479623783653 ], [ 22.155268182064333, -11.084801120653779 ], [ 22.402798292742432, -10.993075453335692 ], [ 22.837345411884769, -11.017621758674338 ], [ 23.456790805767469, -10.867863457892483 ], [ 23.912215203555746, -10.926826267137542 ], [ 24.017893507592618, -11.237298272347118 ], [ 23.904153680118242, -11.722281589406336 ], [ 24.079905226342902, -12.191296888887308 ], [ 23.930922072045377, -12.565847670138822 ], [ 24.016136508894704, -12.911046237848552 ], [ 21.933886346125945, -12.898437188369357 ], [ 21.887842644953878, -16.080310153876894 ], [ 22.56247846852429, -16.898451429921835 ], [ 23.215048455506093, -17.523116143465955 ], [ 21.377176141045595, -17.93063648851971 ], [ 18.956186964603631, -17.789094740472237 ], [ 18.263309360434221, -17.309950860262006 ], [ 14.209706658595053, -17.353100681225712 ], [ 14.058501417709039, -17.423380629142656 ], [ 13.462362094789967, -16.971211846588744 ], [ 12.814081251688407, -16.941342868724078 ], [ 12.215461460019384, -17.111668389558062 ], [ 11.73419884608515, -17.301889336824502 ], [ 11.640096062881611, -16.673142185129208 ], [ 11.778537224991567, -15.793816013250691 ], [ 12.123580763404448, -14.878316338767931 ], [ 12.175618930722266, -14.449143568583892 ], [ 12.500095249083017, -13.547699883684402 ], [ 12.738478631245442, -13.137905775609937 ], [ 13.312913852601838, -12.483630466362513 ], [ 13.633721144269828, -12.038644707897191 ], [ 13.738727654686926, -11.297863050993143 ], [ 13.686379428775297, -10.731075941615842 ], [ 13.387327915102162, -10.373578383020728 ], [ 13.120987583069876, -9.766897067914115 ], [ 12.875369500386569, -9.166933689005489 ], [ 12.929061313537801, -8.959091078327575 ], [ 13.236432732809874, -8.562629489784342 ], [ 12.933040398824318, -7.596538588087753 ], [ 12.72829837408392, -6.927122084178805 ], [ 12.227347039446443, -6.294447523629373 ], [ 12.322431674863566, -6.100092461779653 ], [ 12.735171339578699, -5.965682061388478 ], [ 13.02486941900699, -5.984388929878108 ], [ 13.375597364971895, -5.864241224799557 ], [ 16.326528354567046, -5.877470391466218 ] ] ], [ [ [ 12.436688266660923, -5.684303887559224 ], [ 12.182336866920281, -5.789930515163803 ], [ 11.914963006242118, -5.037986748884734 ], [ 12.318607618873926, -4.606230157086159 ], [ 12.62075971848455, -4.438023369976122 ], [ 12.995517205465205, -4.781103203961919 ], [ 12.631611769265845, -4.991271254092936 ], [ 12.468004184629763, -5.248361504744992 ], [ 12.436688266660923, -5.684303887559224 ] ] ] ] } }
```

An example of the whole page can be found here: 
http://stefanvanderhoorn.nl/experiments/ol_empty_base_geojson.html

Hope someone can help!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more of a JS question to be honest; the easiest way would be iterate over all available attributes and append them to the output (rather than hardcode names of the attributes):

```js
// (...)
featureselected: function (event) {
    var feature = event.feature;
    var infoTable = createInfoTable(feature);
    var output = country + "<br/><br/>" + infoTable;
    document.getElementById("output-id").innerHTML = output;
}
// (...)

function createInfoTable(feature) {
    var headers = {
        "landgrabber": "Land taken by",
        "landgrabbed": "From country"
        "hectares": "Hectares"
        // etc.
    };

    var html = "";

    for (var key in feature.attributes) {
        var value = feature.attributes[attribute];
        var header = headers[key];
        html += header + ": " + value + "<br/>";
    }

    return html;
}
```

You didn't specify your requirements so I covered the simplest scenario, not handling special cases (value is `null`, attribute required/optional, etc.)

Comment: or use map (I use underscore.js):

function createInfoTable(feature) {
    var headers = {
        "landgrabber": "Land taken by",
        "landgrabbed": "From country",
        "hectares": "Hectares"
        // etc.
    };    
    return _.map(headers, function(name, key){        
        return name + ": " + feature.attributes[key];        
    }).join("</br>");
}

Answer (score 0):

if all the features share the same fields in the GeoJSON, just write every field. If not, do the same, just write every field as you did and then add if/else to define which field will be printed and which won't, something like:

```
if (landgrabbed =! null)
else
// etc, etc,
fi
```